# array contents dont come through to php from jquery ajax function

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I am trying to pass an array through to php as a parameter using jquery ajax but I am not be able to get the contents on the php side ... it comes back like so :

```
Array
(
    [attributes] => 
)
```

maybe the associative array that I create in JS is passed through as an object .. but not sure.

Jquery code

```
 $(".submit").on("click", function () {


         var myattributes = new Array();
         $("select").each(function () { 
             myattributes[$(this).attr('id')] = this.value;

         });




         //for(var index in myattributes) {
         // document.write( index + " : " + myattributes[index] + "<br />");
         // }
         //this works



var data = 'attributes=' + myattributes'&act=test';

         $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "myphp.php",
             data: data,
             beforeSend: function (html) { 
                 alert(html);
             },
             success: function (html) { 

                 alert(html);
             },
             complete: function (html) { 
                 alert (html); 
             }
         });

     });
```

PHP (myphp.php):

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['attributes'])  ) {
print_r ($_REQUEST);
//$array=$_REQUEST['attributes'];
//print_r ($array);

//foreach ($array as $key => $value)
// echo $key.'=>'.$value.'<br />';

}
```

Comment: `myattributes` is an array, and you're trying to concatenate it with a string. doesn't work that way.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but can you please point where the concat happens?

Comment: `var data = 'attributes=' + myattributes'&act=test';`

Comment: ok but how can I pass this array through

Comment: I have tried  data: {myattributes:myattributes}, but I am still getting back an empty array

Comment: Initializing the array using var myattributes = {}; and using json stringify to encode and json_decode to decode in php resolved this.

Thanks everyone for answering

Answer (score 0):

If all your `select` elements are part of a form in the html, you can get the data of all form elements at once using:

```
...
url: "myphp.php",
data: $("form").serialize(),
...
```